# CSS (one tab) Isnt Working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, stylesheet

I'm a little new, just built a website for my portfolio. It works perfectly in Internet Explorer and Firefox. However, in Chrome one page doesn't work. It looks as if the stylesheet isn't being recognized.

Here is my site: http://kzdesign.org/

Here is the page that isnt working in Chrome: http://kzdesign.org/ads.html

My nav bar is all over the place, the footer is as well. All my advertisement images arn't on there (or just behind the background image).

**CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#triangles {
position: absolute;
top: -160px;
left: 810px;
}

#home {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px; 
}

#portfolio {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 211px; }

#kz
{position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 581px; }

#about {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 1307px;
}

#contact {
position: absolute; 
top: 0px;
left: 1582px;
height: 2525; 
width: 0px;
}

#text {
position: absolute;
top: 340px;
left: 660px;
}

#next {
position: absolute;
top: 315px;
left: 1400px;
}

#mac {
position: absolute;
top: 500px;
left: 500px;
}

#snowglobe {
position: absolute;
top: 500px;
left: 1020px;
border-color: white; 
border-style: solid;
border-width: 7px;
display: block;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
}

#xmas {
position: absolute;
top: 1000px;
left: 290px;
border-color: white; 
border-style: solid;
border-width: 7px;
display: block;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
}

#monday {
position: absolute;
top: 1430px;
Left: 90px;
border-color: white; 
border-style: solid;
border-width: 7px;
display: block;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
}

#why {
position: absolute;
top: 1430px;
left: 1020px;


}

#llc {
position: absolute;
top: 1000px;
left: 1020px;
border-color: white; 
border-style: solid;
border-width: 7px;
display: block;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
}

#black {
position: absolute;
top: 240px;
left: 0px;
}


#facebook {
position: absolute;
top: 2210px;
left: 0px;
}

#contact_info {
position: absolute;
top: 2210px;
left: 635px;
}

#design {
position: absolute;
top: 2210px;
left: 1343px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Advertisments</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="advertisment_style.css">
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui-effects.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_DW_effectShake(obj,method,effect,direction,distance,times,speed)
{
  obj[method](effect, {direction:direction,distance:distance,times:times}, speed);
}
function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}
</script>
</head>

<h1>    

    <div id="home"><a href="Index/index.html"><img src="Index/images/index_01.png" alt="home" width="211" height="240"></a>
    </div>

<div id="portfolio" onfocus="MM_goToURL('parent','Portfolio/portfolio.html');return document.MM_returnValue"><a href="portfolio.html"><img src="Index/images/index_02.png" alt="portfolio" width="370" height="240"></a>
  </div>

    <div id="kz"> 
 <img src="Index/images/index_03.png" alt="kate_zimmerman" width="726" height="240">
    </div>

   <div id="about"> 
 <img src="Index/images/index_04.png" alt="contact" width="275" height="240" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','About/about.html');return document.MM_returnValue">
  </div>

  <div id="contact"> 
 <img src="Index/images/index_05.png" alt="contact" width="318" height="2358" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','Contact/contact.html');return document.MM_returnValue">
  </div>

<div id="black"> 
<img src="Marketing/black_bg.png" alt="body" height="1975" width="1900px" > 
  </div>

</h1>

<h2>
<div id="text"> 
<img src="Advertisments/ad_text.jpg" alt="text" width="592"> 
    </div>

    <div id="next"> 
    <img src="logos/next.png" alt="next_button" width="450" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','event.html');return document.MM_returnValue">
    </div>

<div id="mac" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','Advertisments/mac n cheese ad_jpeg.jpg');return document.MM_returnValue" onMouseOver="MM_DW_effectShake($(this),'effect','shake','left',20,1,1000)"> 
<img src="Advertisments/mac n cheese ad_jpeg.jpg" alt="food_ad" width="400">    
    </div>

<div id="snowglobe" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','Advertisments/snowglobe ad_jpeg.jpg');return document.MM_returnValue" onMouseOver="MM_DW_effectShake($(this),'effect','shake','left',20,1,1000)">
<img src="Advertisments/snowglobe ad_jpeg.jpg" alt="school_ad" width="400">     
    </div>

    </h2>

<div id="xmas" onMouseOver="MM_DW_effectShake($(this),'effect','shake','left',20,1,1000)">
<img src="Advertisments/facebook_cover_xmas_gif20.gif" alt="christmas_gif" width="600" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','Advertisments/facebook_cover_xmas_gif20.gif');return document.MM_returnValue" >
    </div>

<div id="llc" onMouseOver="MM_DW_effectShake($(this),'effect','shake','left',20,1,1000)">
<img src="Advertisments/advertisment.png" alt="psychotherapy_ad" width="600" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','Advertisments/advertisment.png');return document.MM_returnValue">    
    </div>

<div id="monday" onMouseOver="MM_DW_effectShake($(this),'effect','shake','left',20,1,1000)">
<img src="Advertisments/differencemonday2.jpg" alt="social_media_ad" width="800px" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','Advertisments/differencemonday2.jpg');return document.MM_returnValue"  >
    </div>

<div id="why"> 
<img src="Advertisments/why wednesday_jpeg.jpg" alt="why_wednesday_ad" width="580" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','Advertisments/why wednesday_jpeg.jpg');return document.MM_returnValue" onMouseOver="MM_DW_effectShake($(this),'effect','shake','left',20,1,1000)"> 
    </div>

<h3>

<div id="triangles">    
    <img src="Marketing/triangles.jpg" alt="banner" width="167"> 
</div>

<div id="facebook"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/KateZimmermanDesigns/" target="new"> </a> 
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/KateZimmermanDesigns/" target="new"><img src="Index/images/index_07.png" alt="facebook" width="635" height="167"></a> 
</div>

<div id="contact_info"> 
<img src="Index/images/index_08.png" alt="contact_info" width="708" height="167"> 
  </div>

<div id="design"> 
<img src="Index/images/index_09.png" alt="designed_by_KZ_Graphics" width="557" height="167"> 
  </div>

</h3>

</html>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how it is not working? Could you post the CSS in question?

Comment: Sure! So, it looks like the style-sheet isnt being recognized for that one page in Chrome. My nav bar is all over the place, the footer is as well. All my advertisement images arnt on there (or just behind the background image).   I'll post the HTML and CSS in the original question. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, took me a few minutes on how to post the code correctly :)